# How do I return variables captured from a block to the caller in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm having trouble returning an asynchronous response/error pair captured in a block back to caller. Here is the code:

```
- (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error
{
    __block NSData* b_data = nil;
    __block NSURLResponse* b_response = nil;
    __block NSError* b_error = nil;

    dispatch_semaphore_t wait = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [self sendRequest:request completion:^(NSHTTPURLResponse* c_response, NSData* c_data, NSError* c_error) {

        b_data = c_data;
        b_response = c_response;
        b_error = c_error;

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(wait);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(wait, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    response = &b_response; // ERROR: Assigning NSURLResponse *__strong * to NSURLResponse *__autoreleasing * changes retain/release properties of pointer
    error = &b_error;       // ERROR: Assigning NSError *__strong * to NSError *__autoreleasing * changes retain/release properties of pointer

    return b_data;
}
```

Basically, I'm converting an async request to a synchronous one. I need to return the response/error pair back to the caller through a pointer-to-a-pointer. However, I'm running into some problems with ARC and blocks.

I would like to copy the response/error out of the block and return it to the caller without changing the method signature (there is a slew of legacy code that calls this method - I'm trying to gingerly replace NSURLConnection with NSURLSession).

Is there a nice way I can extract the results and return them to the caller?

Comment: Wow. That is a super embarrassing pointer screwup. I'm overwriting the parameter instead of dereferencing it and writing the result. I'll leave this here as an example of what NOT to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two errors have nothing to do with the block. Those lines should be:

```
if (response) {
    *response = b_response;
}
if (error) {
    *error = b_error;
}
```

The `if` checks are required incase the caller passes `nil` for the parameter. You will get a crash trying to dereference a `nil` pointer.

It's also unnecessary to copy the response/error pair to local __block variables. You can write them directly to the parameter after checking for `nil`.